# Request.getParameter to int?

Tags: java, jsp, calculator

Ok, so I have a university project to make a pretty simple calculator in JSP. Thing is I get an error on the result=a(x)b lines because of bad operand for binary operation"x" where X the symbol of function I want to do.
I'm not sure what's going wrong... a+b says I cant convert strings to int but I can't do a Integer a=request.getParameter... etc
Any help or tips are much appreciated...

This is my index.html

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>Calculator</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form name="Parameters" method="post" action="calc.jsp">
                <i>You know you have a built-in calculator in your OS, right?</i><br><br>

                Number 1: <input type="text" name="param1"><p>
                Number 2: <input type="text" name="param2"><p>
                Function: <input type="text" name="function" maxlength="1"><br><br>
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And this is my calc.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : calc
    Created on : May 8, 2015, 2:45:00 AM
    Author     : Doom
--%>
>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%    
int result;
String resp;
String a=request.getParameter("param1");
String b=request.getParameter("param2");
String f=request.getParameter("function");

if (f.equals("+"))
    result= a+b;
else if(f.equals("-"))
    result=a-b;
else if(f.equals("*"))
    result=a*b;
else if(f.equals("/"))
    result=a/b;
else
    resp="Invalid Function";
%>r
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `Integer.parseInt (str)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing a calculator you probably want to convert your string input to `double` rather than `int`. In which case the solution is:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(aString);
```

Your `result` will definitely need to be a double if you want the results of divisions to appear properly, when when dividing integers.

You will also want to handle exceptions where the user submitted non-numeric values.